# Hide first 8 digits using substr() in Magento credit card information

Tags: javascript

how to hide first 8 digits in following code using `substr()`:

```
$data[Mage::helper('payment')->__('Credit Card Number')] =
    sprintf('xxxx-%s', $this->getInfo()->getNumber());
```

As I'm new to JS, please edit the code and post here

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: please visit this link :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26228910/hide-last-4-digits-of-credit-card-number-in-magento-admin-panel/26229034?noredirect=1#comment41139354_26229034

Thanks a lot for Amit.

Comment: Hi @programmer_rkt , thanks a lot for editing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've posted is in PHP:

[PHP: substr - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

If you're looking for the JS equivalent:

[JavaScript String substring() Method - W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp)

**In PHP for example:**

```
$card_number = $this->getInfo()->getNumber());
$card_number_cut = substr($card_number, 8, strlen($card_number));
```

**In JS for example:**

```
var card_number = //blah blah blah
card_number = card_number.substring(8, card_number.length);
```

Let me know if you have any problems.

**Edit for your example in specific:**

```
$data[Mage::helper('payment')->__('Credit Card Number')] = sprintf('xxxx-xxxx-%s',
    substr($this->getInfo()->getNumber(), 8,
        strlen($this->getInfo()->getNumber())
    )
);
```

Comment: hi moose, thanks a lot for your help. I really got a good knowledge after seeing your answer.